# Indian student going to study in France. Is the original birth certificate mandatory?

Tags: visa, france

I am an Indian student going to Grenoble Ecole De Management, France, later this year. While preparing my documents, I was told that apostilled and translated original birth certificate would be needed for several administrative procedures, including housing benefit, health insurance and most importantly, to renew my visa for the second year.

Unfortunately, I do not have an original birth certificate. I was born at home in a village in Kerala in '84 and have been domiciled in Bangalore ever since. While joining school, I believe my parents got an affidavit of birth from a notary/lawyer and used it for admission. I don't have this document with me anymore.

I am in a fix now. I do not know whether I can proceed with my plan of going to France at all without an original birth certificate. I don't mind losing the housing benefit but obviously I need to be able to renew the visa for the second year. Is this a dead end or will French authorities accept an apostilled affidavit of birth from a notary or lawyer in Bangalore (in lieu of the original birth certificate)?

This information is critical for me because if there is really no way to renew my visa without an original birth certificate, then it means I cannot go to France at all (my course is for two years). The student integration team at Grenoble told me that no other document will be accepted. But Campus France tells me that it is only needed for the housing benefit and not needed for the visa, so I am confused. Where do I get some reliable info and is it a good idea to proceed if I am unable to produce get this document?

Comment: In my experience they won't know the difference. I didn't realise there was a difference between a 'certificate of birth' and a 'long form birth certificate' and I the first, without apostille, for my original visa and the renewal. It was fine. It's also not the original BC they need - it's one dated within 6 months. But this is not enforced terribly often. Don't take this as gospel, but I think get whatever you can + apostille, and it should be fine.